# Output outside my char array range, while using rand()

Tags: c++, arrays, random

I'm making a memory game(not going good so far) and I've encountered this problem, my random function or my loop in the new_game function seem to be haywire.
I'm a beginner in c++ so any help will be much appreciated. I know the code is a bit unorganized and clumsy, not to mention not optimized. New to all that.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void main_menu();
////////////NECESSARY VARIABLES////////////
int score=0;
int highscore;

//////////NECESSARY FILE HANDLERS//////////
fstream filehandlerHS;
//^^^HIGH SCORE STATS^^^//

//////////FUNCTION TO CREATE RANDOM STRING//////////

char vocab[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};////POSSIBLE CHARACTERS

char random()
{
    return vocab[rand() %10];
}

///////////////NEW GAME/////////////
void New_Game()
{
    cout<<"......Welcome To The Memory Game!.......";
    cout<<"A series of random characters will be shown to you\n"
        <<"For a specific period of time, you have to remember it\n"
        <<"And once the text dissapears, enter it, correct answers gives 5        points\n"
        <<"Wrong answer means game over! ready? \n";
    system("Pause");
    system("cls");
    for(int i=0; i<10;i++)
    {
        char entry[9];
        char term[9];
        for(int j=0; j<i;j++)
        {
            term[j]=random();   
        }
        cout<<term;
        system("pause");
        system("cls");
        cin>>entry;
        if(entry==term)
        {
            score+=5;
        }
        if(entry!=term)
        {
            cout<<"Ooops! Wrong Guess!!! GAME OVER!!!";
            if(score>highscore)
            {
                cout<<"High Score! your record has been saved!";
                filehandlerHS.close();
                filehandlerHS.open("C:/Users/bhati/Documents/C-Free/Projects/GuessGame/HighScore.dat", ios::trunc);
                filehandlerHS<<score;
            }               
            break;
        }
    }
    cout<<"Your Score  :: "<<score;
    system("pause");
    main_menu();
}

////////////////////////TO VIEW HIGHSCORE//////////////
void High_Score()
{
    system("cls");
    cout<<"............**HIGH SCORE DETAILS**.........";
    cout<<"\n\n\n";
    cout<<"Your highest score in game is...... \n";
    filehandlerHS>>highscore;
    cout<<highscore<<"!!!";
    cout<<"\n Awesome Job!!";
}

////////////TO RESET SCORE//////////////////
void High_Reset()
{
    char ch;
    system("cls");
    cout<<"Are you sure? all your glory will be lost.Y/N \n";
    cin>>ch;
    if(ch=='Y'||ch=='y')
    {
        filehandlerHS.close();
        filehandlerHS.open("C:/Users/bhati/Documents/C-Free/Projects/GuessGame/HighScore.dat", ios::trunc);
        cout<<"DONE!!!!!!!!!!!!\n\n";
    }
    cout<<"Phew!! going back to main menu!";
    system("pause");
    main_menu();

}

////////////////Main Menu/////////////////
void main_menu()
{
    system("cls");
    int main_menu_choice=0;
    cout<<"\t\t******************MAIN MENU******************\n";
    cout<<"\t\t* 1. New Game                               *\n";
    cout<<"\t\t* 3. High Score                             *\n";
    cout<<"\t\t* 4. Reset High Score                       *\n";
    cout<<"\t\t* Please Enter your Choice(1-4)....         *\n";
    cout<<"\t\t*********************************************\n";
    cin>>main_menu_choice; 
    switch(main_menu_choice)
    {
        case 1 : New_Game();
                 break;
        case 3 : High_Score();
                 break;
        case 4 : High_Reset();
                 break;
        default : cout<<"Invalid Choice, please try again.";
                  break;    
    }
}

int main()
{
    filehandlerHS.open("C:/Users/bhati/Documents/C-Free/Projects/GuessGame/HighScore.dat");
    filehandlerHS>>highscore;
    main_menu();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how your program goes "haywire"? And if the `High_Score`, `High_Reset` and `main_menu` functions are not related to your problem, then we don't really need to see them. Please try to create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? And also please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that

```
cout << term;
```

doesn't do what you think it does. Since `term` is declared as an array of `char`, it thinks it's a C-style character string, not an array of numbers. So it's treating the contents of the array as character codes, and expects it to end with a null byte. You're getting garbage because the numbers `0` through `9` are control characters.

First, `vocab` should contain the characters you want to display, not numbers:

```
char vocab[]={'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};////POSSIBLE CHARACTERS
```

or more simply:

```
char vocab[] = "0123456789";
```

Then, you should use `std::string` instead of a `char` array.

```
std::string entry;
std::string term;
for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    term.push_back(random());
}
cin >> entry;
if (entry == term) {
    ...
}
```

You also can't compare arrays with `==`. If you want to tell if two arrays contain the same values, you need to loop over them, comparing them element by element. But using `std::string` for `term` and `entry` solves that as well.

Comment: There is also an out-of-bounds access going on in the loop:`for(int j=0; j<i;j++)
        {
            term[j]=random();   
        }` since term only has 9 elements

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall I thought so, too, but changed my mind. The outer loop is `i < 10`, so the last iteration is `i == 9`. This loop uses `j < i`, so the last iteration is `j == 8`, so it's in bounds.

Comment: Yep, you're totally right. For some reason I misread the loop's condition as `j<=i`...